# Can Qt3 designed UI can be converted to Qt5 UI form?

Tags: user-interface, qt5, qt3

is it possible to convert *Qt3* designed UI to *Qt5* UI form?

I have a huge quantities of forms that must be transfered. The only way out I can see for now, is to make a brand new ones.

I tried to open *.ui* file via *Qt5*, it returned error:

> This file was created using Designer from Qt-3.3 and cannot be read.
>   Do you want to update the file location or generate a new form?

Answer (score 0):

Qt 4 came with a tool called uic3. This allows you to convert them to the Qt 4 uic format, which might help in using them with Qt5. Though, if deprecated widgets from Qt 3 were used,  you'll probably need manual editing.